# I updated to Ubuntu 11.04 and It broke my installation

Tags: unity, update-manager, updates

I tried to update to Natty Narwhal with `update-manager -d` and then I followed through everything and then when I restarted everything broke. Told me to put in some code or something but then after I restarted I couldn't find where to put the code in.

Comment: You will need to put a few more details, the exact messages you're getting, what 'code' you're talking about and so on, in the question for us to be able to answer it.

Answer (score 4):

Let me say it a little bit different: if you dont have the knowledge to help yourself out of such problems, you should NEVER upgrade to a developing version, especially if it is such an early one

Comment: Well, sure you can - to get experience - but doing it with important data is perhaps a bit optimistic.

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the things that happen when you upgrade to an unreleased beta-version.

Restore your latest backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can report your problems to the people who is developing it, so they can fix it for the others, of for yourself if you finally end up installing 10.10 again. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Occurs in June 2011

I'm on  intel, not amd;

-----error message from terminal-----

Compiling /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/enthought/util/guisupport.py ...
SyntaxError ('future feature absolute_import is not defined',)